# MYSQL WORKBENCH syntax warning/error although it got executed

Tags: mysql-workbench

I installed the latest version of MYSQL workbench 6.3.8 - it is giving syntax error icon at line number column although the syntax is correct and executed. Below is screen shot.  Could you please advice me if I have done mistake in the query (although the query executed).

[image]
EDIT: This does not occur if there is a sub query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a known problem. Error markers in the gutter aren't properly removed (those in the text are, however). A quick solution is to cut out the text and paste it back. This issue will be addressed in the next release of MySQL Workbench.